# AWS s3:access denied while uploading file

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload a file to AWS s3 buckets via php sdk,in order to do that i've created an IAM user and added an inline policy

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:DeleteObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is my php code

```
$s3 = new S3Client([
    'version' => 'latest',
    'region'  => 'ap-south-1',
    'credentials' =>
        array(
            'key'=>'X',
            'secret'  =>'X'
       )
]);

try {
    $s3->putObject([
        'Bucket' => 'candy-prototype',
        'Key'    => 'my-object.txt',
        'Body'   => fopen('test.txt', 'r'),
        'ACL'    => 'public-read',
    ]);
} catch (Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
    echo "There was an error uploading the file.\n";
}
```

But it will thrown access denied exception

> ```
> Error executing "PutObject" on "https://s3.<region>.amazonaws.com/bucket/my-object.txt"; AWS HTTP
> ```
>
> error: Client error: `PUT
>   https://s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/candy-prototype/my-object.txt`
>   resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: AccessDeniedAccess
>   DeniedC21D9D (truncated...) AccessDenied (client): Access Denied -
>   AccessDeniedAcces
>   **UPDATE**

Granted read and write permission to `everyone` but it dosen't worked.
**IAM user can able to upload/delete/view from aws web adminpanel,but the api access is denied**

Answer (score 1):

ListBucket & GetBucketLocation should be applied to bucket , not bucket/*
Change the resource in the first part of the policy

```
{
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::bucket"
    },
```

Refer [this](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/writing-iam-policies-how-to-grant-access-to-an-amazon-s3-bucket/) documentation